# Where should i add New code signing identity stuff in xamarin studio?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run previously code signed app source code on an iOS device using xamarin studio. 
Since I have to code sign it with the new identity for my device.
where should i add the code sign stuff in xamarin studio.
well....
in xcode i could do this under the "build setting->code signing" section.
but xamarin doesn't have this kinda stuff inside, i guess

I have already added my Apple Dev. Account in Xamarin Preferences. and included in in info.plist under the "Team" section.

but nothing seems to work..

When i run the app i.e debug the app on an iPad

it still asks for the previous code sign identity.

what am i missing ? 
or 
is it not possible to code sign a previously code signed app with a different identity in xamarin studio. ?

PS. :- i am using xamarin studio version 4.2.2

**EDIT in favor of binncheol answer**

i don't think there is anything like "Option' > 'iOS Build Setting"
have a look at my screen shot of the tool bar.
[image]

also..
if you meant 'Options' by 'preferences'

here is screen shot of my preference window in xamarin.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the 'Options' > 'iOS Bundle Signing' menu for your iOS project in Xamarin Studio you should  be able to select your identity and provisioning profiles.

Comment: This is because you are in 'preferences'. If you right click on your project, in the drop menu you will see 'Options', this is where you will find your iOS Bundle Signing settings.